# how to use web_reg_save_param_xpath in load runner?

Tags: performance, loadrunner

I have below response for one of the request I would to fetch the value 5 using web_reg_save_param_xpath, I have tried with below expression.

Expression:

```
web_reg_save_param_xpath(
    "ParamName=WarehouseId",
    "ReturnXml=No",
    "QueryString=.//select[@id='WareHouseId']/option[@selected='selected']/@value",
    "SelectAll=No",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=BODY",
    LAST);
```

Response data:

```
 <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Warehouse must be a number." data-val-range="[Warehouse] Minimum value should be 0" data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-regex="[Warehouse] Please enter valid input." data-val-regex-pattern="[0-9]+$" data-val-required="Warehouse is mandatory." id="WareHouseId" name="WareHouseId">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="4">Hospital</option>
<option selected="selected" value="5">Warehouse</option>
<option value="6">SUPPLY</option>
</select>
```

but it throwing below error

```
Action.c(301): Error: lr_xml_get_values_reg_save_param execution failed
Action.c(301): Notify: Saving Parameter "ReasonId = 4".
Action.c(301): Notify: Saving Parameter "WarehouseId = ".
Action.c(301): Error -35060: No matches were found for the specified query: ".//select[@id="WareHouseId"]/option[@selected="selected"]/@value"      [MsgId: MERR-35060]
```

Comment: Vivek, you must provide the error that's being thrown. Without it, we are not able to help :-(

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu I have attached the error details,Kindly help

Comment: I can't help you since I don't know loadrunner. Your XPATH seems ok (here's a test https://jsfiddle.net/b0e3n4pa/17/).

Comment: How long have you used loadrunner, have you been through training, do you have a mentor assisting you?

Comment: I am new to load runner, I am learning myself in my free time and I do not have any mentor.

Comment: This path is not recommended and typically results in users who struggle to deliver value for half a decade or more.  The most common reason why a properly parameterized service function (i.e. web_reg_....) fails is because it has been placed in the wrong location.  Service functions are placed directly prior to the statement which generates the output for evaluation, with the service function acting as a sieve to filter the value from the returning stream.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Hitchhiking-Guide-Testing-Projects-Step/dp/0988540207/ref=pd_sim_1/140-5352585-3523257

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Interviewing-Hiring-Software-Performance-Professionals/dp/0988540266/ref=sr_1_3